# Knit one purl one

Tags: language, word-property

Actually the title is completely misleading because this has nothing to do with knitting. Here is the actual puzzle.

---

Pull one.

Cost two.

Get off one.

Off the top of one.

Keep one up.

Bite one.

Drag two.

Cross two.

---

Note I shall add some easier ones as time goes by unless someone gets it first.

---

**Question**

(a) What sort of thing are these "ones" and "twos"?  ---- ----- (4, 5)

and

(b) What common linguistic phenomenon are they part of?  ------ (5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all

> **body parts**

and they are all

> part of common **idiom**s.

---

Pull one.

> "pull my finger" (or "pulling my leg"?)

Cost two.

> "cost an arm and a leg"

Get off one.

> "get off my rear"?

Off the top of one.

> "off the top of my head"

Keep one up.

> "keep your chin up"

Bite one.

> "bite my ass"

Drag two.

> "drag one's feet" and "drag one's heels"?

Cross two.

> "cross my heart" and "cross my fingers"

Comment: Sniped! Well played. Although not all the same as the ones I thought up - there are quite a lot of answers which fit these...

Comment: @Stiv Yeah, I wouldn't be surprised if there were a lot more that could fit. I'd bet some of these could go up to at least four.

Comment: Indeed. You can also have rot13(chyy grrgu, ovgr lbhe yvc/gbathr, pebff yrtf/nezf/rlrf...)

Comment: Yes, you have the correct terms (a) and (b). As you say, there are multiple possibilities for some of the ones I chose and many more I didn't choose.